# background-size: cover; Not filling site

Tags: html, css

So I am trying to make the background fill the page, but it just won't do it. I have no idea why:

```
#background {  
  background: linear-gradient(to top, rgb(226, 250, 218), rgb(0, 116, 25)) center center fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

Can someone help me? I am quite new to HTML and CSS and don't really understand everything perfectly.

Here is the HTML Code too:

```
    <div class="center" id="background">
  <div class="img-wrapper border slow zoom">
    <header>Welcome to my Journal!</header>
  </div>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <h4> Diese Sprachen habe ich bis jetzt gelernt: </h4>
  <label for="python">
  <input id="python" value="python" type="checkbox" name="code" checked>Python
  </label>
  <br>
  <label for="java">
  <input id="java" value="java" type="checkbox" name="code">Java
  </label>
  <br>
  <label for="html">
  <input id="html" value="html" type="checkbox" name="code" checked>HTML
  </label>
  <br>
  <label for="c">
  <input id="c" value="c" type="checkbox" name="code">C++
  </label>
</div>
```

EDIT:
It turned out to be the default margin of the body was set to 8px by the website!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Comment: You HTML code isnt enough to answer this. you need to post your full related code. and this stage i would say your DIV hasnt a height and width because you didnt set any widht/height and the DIV hasnt any childs. but im pretty sure there is more code to post.

Comment: Okay, I'll see what I have to post. One sec!

Comment: `background-size: cover` does not "fill the site", it fills the area covered by the element you apply it to. Did you do anything to _make_ `#background` cover the full site? (The more correct term would be page, not site, btw. The term "site" is usually used for the complete content under a specific domain.)

Comment: I tried using width: 100%, and height: 100%; but it didn't work. Sorry for the wrong term, I am German :D

Comment: If you want to align elements, I strongly recommend you to use css style instead of `<br>`

Answer (score 0):

write something between your div like below:-

```
<div class="center" id="background"><span>write here</span></div>
```

or give height and width in your css like this:-

```
#background {
    background: linear-gradient(to top, rgb(226, 250, 218), rgb(0, 116, 25)) center center;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
}
```

Comment: The second thing worked in a way, now the background goes to the edge on the bottom and right side.

Answer (score -2):

I don't know what's in your div, but your code should work.
Do you have a width/height for your div, or some content inside?
Just an example here:

```css
#background {
  background: linear-gradient(to top, rgb(226, 250, 218), rgb(0, 116, 25))
    center center fixed;
  height: 100vh;
  width: calc(100vw - 15px);
padding-left: 15px;
}
header {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 2em;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 0.15em;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}
.choices{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  max-width: 300px;
  gap: 10px;
}
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<body>
  <div class="center" id="background">
    <header>Welcome to my Journal!</header>
    <h4> Diese Sprachen habe ich bis jetzt gelernt: </h4>
<div class="choices">
  <div clas="choice">
    <input id="python" value="python" type="checkbox" name="code" checked>
    <label for="python">Python </label>
  </div><div clas="choice">
    <input id="java" value="java" type="checkbox" name="code"> <label for="java">Java
    </label>
  </div><div clas="choice">
    <input id="html" value="html" type="checkbox" name="code" checked> <label for="html">HTML
    </label>
  </div><div clas="choice">
    <input id="c" value="c" type="checkbox" name="code"> <label for="c">C++
    </label>  </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```